# Attach/associate Selenium WebDriver Automation scripts with TFS Manual Test

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have test scripts in Selenium Webdriver using Java language. I want to attach/associate these test scripts with the manual test cases in MS-TFS. I have already done the integration between TFS and eclipse using the Add-on provided by Microsoft. Due to this I am only able to check-in/check-out the code in TFS. But not able to associate the test scripts with manual test cases.

Is there any solution for this?